# Filtering RTF codes from text in C#

Tags: c#, regex, rtf

I am trying to parse data that I receive as a text file. My goal is to remove the formatting codesIt appears to be in Rich Text Format, but I suspect it contains some proprietary codes. I suspect this because when I run the following code, I get an error that says 'File format is not valid.'

```
    public static string RemoveRTF(string rtfString)
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Rtf = rtfString;
        return rtb.Text;
    }
```

I have tried using a string aggregate, as in the code below, to remove specific codes.

```
public static string RemoveSpecificCodes(string text)
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    words.Add("\\par\\pard");
    words.Add("\\pard\\par");
    words.Add("\\pard");
    words.Add("\\par");
    words.Add("\\~");
    output = words.Aggregate(text, (input, word) => input.Replace(word, ""));
    return output;
}
```

This approach works if I know all of the format codes, but I have >10,000 lines to process, and I don't have a list of all of the codes (there appears to be a lot of them). I suspect regex may be a more appropriate way to remove the codes, but I know virtually nothing about regular expressions. Can someone help me get started? The text doesn't have any backslashes, so I would like to identify the format codes by finding a backslash, and then deleting the backslash and everything up to, but not including the next backslash or space.

Comment: One option is to list all the codes, and then use StringBuilder.Replace (and not string.Replace). It would likely be the fastest solution. Be warned that Microsoft does not support RTF. It may be documented (but still not supported)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Flydog57. I was hoping to not use a hard-coded list of codes. I don't control the content of the text files and can't guarantee that another code won't be added to the files later. That is why I wanted to use regex.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the RTF codes?  Regex may be a solution, but you need some kind of pattern to match.